# "I was glad because I have seen you." Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> I was glad because I have seen you.

Is this correct?

Can I use the present perfect after "because" when the first sentence is in the simple past?

Comment: It’s unclear how the tense of the presented sentence should be constrained by the tense of the unpresented “first sentence” that is in the past tense.

Comment: I mean the first clause

Comment: Comments are treated as ephemeral on this site. Please [edit] the question directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two clauses joined by a conjunction do not have to share the same tense, so your sentence is grammatical, but it is nonsensical because it violates causality -- something in the present cannot cause something in the past.

Comment: What about I had seen you

Comment: Yes, when the cause is 'past perfect', it is even farther in the past than the 'simple past' result, which is logical for causality.